# Change data in component from Vue root method

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I need to change a value in a component via a method in my Vue root.

My structure looks like this:

```
Root
  PostAnswer
    data:
      valueToChange: 'Blah blah blah'
```

My method is working fine but I cannot get this right.

I've read up on using $emit but I can't get it to work in this instance. Basically I need something like:

```
$root.PostAnswer.data.valueToChange = null;
```

Comment: Use a property?

Comment: Hi @BertEvans thanks, a colleague figured it out using bus to emit to a new function that handled that in the component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should definitely use event.

In the root just emit an event and in the component just catch it.

For example:
In the route:

`window.Event = new Vue();`

Than you emit (still in the root) when you want to reset the value in the component:

`Event.$emit('reset');`

In the component:

```
mounted() {
  Event.$on('reset', () => {
    valueToChange = null;
  });
}
```